# redis as app's system configuration storage

Tags: redis

In my node-based app I plan to use **redis** for a number of purposes, basically interprocess pub/sub communication and a on-line users cache. This application is clear.

I am thinking about where to store the basic app's system configuration. Critical elements like main TCP port, default message channel, database name, admin-user password, etc. would go here.

The traditional choice for the implementation of this kind of thing would be a conf-file, maybe a JSON-structure in a plain text file.

I am wondering however if it would make sense to use **redis** here. The major issue is data reliability and the risk of loss of data.

What are the pros/cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claims against Redis reliability are because of the async nature of its data persistence and replication mechanisms. Being async, these can't guarantee that all updates will endure failures - depending on how you configure Redis, there's a (small) chance that the most recent updates will be lost if there's a failure.

That said, in the context of configuration settings storage, this isn't really an issue. Configuration data is immutable most of the time and if you, by some bizarre coincidence, lose you most recent updates to it, recovering the changes manually (I.e. reconfiguring) is usually trivial.